# one-to-many joining pandas dataframes as a JSON instead of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

```
dept = pd.DataFrame({'dep_id': [1,2], 'dep_name':['shoes', 'giraffes']})
emp = pd.DataFrame({'dep_id': [1,1,2], 'emp_name': ['joe', 'bo', 'gigi']})
```

joining them duplicates `dept` rows for every row in `emp` , as customary in relational joins:

```
pd.merge(dept, emp, on = 'dep_id')

dep_id  dep_name emp_name
0       1     shoes      joe
1       1     shoes       bo
2       2  giraffes     gigi
```

instead, I would like to create a hierarchical JSON: e.g.

```
[ 
{ dep_name: 'shoes', emps: [{emp_name: 'joe'}, {emp_name: 'bo'}]},
{ dep_name: 'giraffes', emps: [{emp_name: 'gigi'}]}
]
```

what's an elegant way to do it? I can join and then groupby, but then its impossible to tell which columns go to the outer dep and which go to the emps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is define columns to `emps` list of DataFrames in `apply`:

```
d = (pd.merge(dept, emp, on = 'dep_id')
      .groupby('dep_name').apply(lambda x: x[['emp_name']]
      .to_dict('r'))
      .reset_index(name='emps'))

print (d)
   dep_name                                       emps
0  giraffes                     [{'emp_name': 'gigi'}]
1     shoes  [{'emp_name': 'joe'}, {'emp_name': 'bo'}]


j = d.to_json(orient='records')
print (j)
[{"dep_name":"giraffes","emps":[{"emp_name":"gigi"}]},
  {"dep_name":"shoes","emps":[{"emp_name":"joe"},{"emp_name":"bo"}]}]
```

```
d = (pd.merge(dept, emp, on = 'dep_id')
      .groupby('dep_name').apply(lambda x: x[['emp_name', 'dep_id']]
      .to_dict('r'))
      .reset_index(name='emps'))

print (d)
   dep_name                                               emps
0  giraffes                [{'dep_id': 2, 'emp_name': 'gigi'}]
1     shoes  [{'dep_id': 1, 'emp_name': 'joe'}, {'dep_id': ...

j = d.to_json(orient='records')
print (j)
[{"dep_name":"giraffes","emps":[{"dep_id":2,"emp_name":"gigi"}]},
  {"dep_name":"shoes","emps":[{"dep_id":1,"emp_name":"joe"},{"dep_id":1,"emp_name":"bo"}]}]
```

EDIT1:

I think for all columns converted out of nested json need:

```
dept = pd.DataFrame({'dep_id': [1,2], 'dep_name':['shoes', 'giraffes'], 'def_size':[4,5]})
emp = pd.DataFrame({'dep_id': [1,1,2], 'emp_name': ['joe', 'bo', 'gigi']})

df = pd.merge(dept, emp, on = 'dep_id')
#single columns def_size and dep_name
d = (df.groupby(['def_size','dep_name']).apply(lambda x: x[['emp_name']]
      .to_dict('r'))
      .reset_index(name='emps'))
print (d)
   def_size  dep_name                                       emps
0         4     shoes  [{'emp_name': 'joe'}, {'emp_name': 'bo'}]
1         5  giraffes                     [{'emp_name': 'gigi'}]

j = d.to_json(orient='records')
print (j)
[{"def_size":4,"dep_name":"shoes","emps":[{"emp_name":"joe"},{"emp_name":"bo"}]},
  {"def_size":5,"dep_name":"giraffes","emps":[{"emp_name":"gigi"}]}]
```

Comment: wow! and if the department had other attributes, e.g. `dep_size`? would I have to groupby all the dept columns?

Comment: @ihadanny - new columnsi used for `merge` like `pd.merge(dept, emp, on = ['dep_id', 'dep_size'])` ? Or need change `x[['emp_name', 'dep_id']]` to `x[['emp_name', 'dep_size']]` ?

Comment: no @jezrael, `dep_size` is not used for the join, only `dep_id` is needed. I would like it to appear in the json only once per dept, not as you suggested once per emp

Comment: cool! then groupby all interesting dept columns is the way we go